# New Users—Cutting Slack?

Tags: discussion, new-users

I keep wondering this: if somebody with 13 rep writes an answer instead of a comment (because they can't) is it appropriate to downvote that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Good question.
My answer in short - *it depends entirely on what they've posted*.

I remember starting on here and being very frustrated that I couldn't comment (I'd been a reader of SO for some time, so had a pretty good understanding of how things worked before I started). Okay, 50 rep isn't a *lot*, but it's still a fair barrier against a brand new user interacting outside of the first few questions/answer that they post.

It's a balance we need to achieve between preventing clutter/noise on the site and making sure we don't discourage new users. And it's a difficult balance to get right, particularly considering so many users can vote down, and most of them will not be involved in this conversation.

*Personally*, I'm more inclined to go with a gentle reminder, where suitable, but ultimately it depends entirely on what they have posted:

- If it **adds value** then it should be kept live and therefore doesn't deserve down-voting, but nudging the user to re-post as a comment (maybe at a later time) is the way forward to keep the site tidy.
- If their comment **adds nothing** then it *deserves deletion*, and the best way to encourage that is by a down-vote (unless it's also offensive/etc in which case flagging is better).

#### Final thought

Remember that if these users *delete* the response that they will get all lost rep back again (possibly after a recalc?), as will those who downvoted. So this is not necessarily *permanent* damage to the users rep - unless, of course, we scare them off.

Comment: we probably also need a moderator-only "force answer to comment on question" function

Comment: regarding "... if these users delete the response that they will get all lost rep back ..." may I ask, where is that documented, please? I'll bet you that most users (especially new users) don't know that.

Comment: @Beel a very good point. If it is documented, it'd be somewhere on Meta.SO - here are [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/reedem-reputation-for-deleted-negative-answers) [examples](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18308/how-do-deleted-posts-affect-rep). But there's a few quirks with the reputation system that having denormalised scores causes, and a delayed removal of all rep changes caused by deleted posts is probably the most prominent. If you ever want your 100% real calculated rep (or a recalculation of your denormalised value) visit http://superuser.com/reputation